# RowMapper returns different column Ordering

Tags: prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I am implementing a row mapper to format the results from a specific query.  When  I query my DB through PG admin, or just using a simple jdbctemplate.queryforlist the columns return in one order but when running using my RowMapper it returns in a completely different order that is in no way related to how i run the other queries (example query: select * from blah.mytable).  Any ideas why a RowMapper would cause the columns to return in a different order?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was using a HashMap instead of a LinkedHasMap when I returned my results.

Thanks,
Brian